# Odoo V10 - Retrieve a value a previous record for same model

Tags: python, odoo

Here my function for a calculated field :

```
# Fonction qui récupère la valeur du champs booléen inscription de l'année précédente
    @api.depends('half_pension')
    def _retrieve_halfpension_previous(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.half_pension:
                record.half_pension_previous = record.half_pension
```

Here my fields :

```
half_pension = fields.Boolean(string='Catering', copy=False)
half_pension_previous = fields.Boolean(string='previously registered', copy=False, store=False,
                                       compute='_retrieve_halfpension_previous')
```

Here my view :

```
<!-- Vue Tree enfants scolarisés cantine-->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="halfpension_view_tree">
        <field name="name">halfpension.view.tree</field>
        <field name="model">ecole.partner.school</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree editable="bottom" default_order="half_pension_id" string="school_halfpension_tree">
                <field name="partner_id" readonly="1" />
                <field name="half_pension" />
                <field name="half_pension_id" />
                <field name="school_name_id" />
                <field name="half_pension_begin_date" />
                <field name="half_pension_end_date" />
                <field name="half_pension_text" />
                <field name="half_pension_previous" />
                <field name="default_school_year" invisible="1" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Currently, I get the same value of "" in my field "". However, I want to retrieve the value of the previous record for the same partner instead of the current record. How to do ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could save the record into a partner field to be able to track the last record of that partner. You will need to change the record in the partner based on your desired event. For example on new record created by overriding the create method of the `ecole.partner.school` model to attach the created record as the partner last record.

After that resolve the value for the `half_pension_previous` field against the partner attached record `half_pension` field